# How to make SXA search on particular Data folder?

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

I'm using SXA 1.7 and Sitecore 9.0.1.

I have created a folder under the Site node and when my search should check the field values under the folder. For this I have created a `search scope`. I'm confused what needs to be added under Scope query and Boosting rule.

Under boosting rule I have specified some conditions but nothing is working. Can anyone please explain clearly what needs to be added in scope query and Boosting rule.
[image]

**Step 1**: Created a Search component and SearchResult component using SXA and specified the search scope name.
**Step 2**: created a template called Book template where it has 3 fields after that created a folder under site named as "searchdata" and added values to  the template created .
**Step 3**: When I click on search its not giving any results from the folder which is created under site but I can retrieve other data which is from the pages created under the Home item. In the search scope query I have added the location for the folder but still it's not working.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The query should have the folder (as I assume you have in the screenshot) and you don't need rules for your requirement. If this is not working, we will need some more information about what you have done and what is not working.

Comment: I have created the search component and specified the search scope for it. In CMS Under site i have created one folder under that i have added some data  and under scope query what needs to be sent as query@Gatogordo

Comment: Try to add more information to the question (edit it)..  Show us all the steps you did, and the results and how they are not what you expect.

Comment: @Vinaya Just can you try removing the rule and then try retrieving the results? Also make sure the items you are trying to retrieve is available in sxa_master_index and sxa_web_index respectively.

Comment: @Gatogordo edited the steps

Comment: @SreeKrishnan if i don't add any rules only simple search will work but the data inside the folder is not getting retrieved

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: include the needed base template**

To include items created using a custom template into search results, you have to inherit the `_Searchable` base template (/sitecore/Templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Search/Computed Fields/_Searchable).

**Step 2: your data is not in the "site"**

As your data is not an actual page in the site, that might cause issues. I haven't tried this myself, but Peter describes a solution to handle those items in his blogpost: https://tothecore.sk/2020/02/20/how-to-crawl-items-in-non-sxa-locations/

Unfortunately the best solution is new in 9.3 (use `_SearchableWithoutRelatedItems` as base template). But according to the blog there is way around: expand the SXA indexes (master and web) with one more crawler (default Sitecore crawler) and aim it to the necessary location.

Note also that as the items are not in your site node, you won't be able to create a link to them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following solution yet? If not, please have a look at it.

Step 1 : Inherit _searchable template (/sitecore/Templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Search/Computed Fields/_Searchable) into your template

Step 2 : Include your Data folder into associated content field(under search criteria section) in Site Settings folder(/sitecore/content/YOURSITE/Settings) like below

[image]

Detailed answer :

[How to make SXA search on Data folder](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30889/how-to-make-sxa-search-on-data-folder)

I have tried and it works!

Hope it helps !

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/15249)

Comment: Made the edits. Thanks.