# How to make SXA search on Data folder

Tags: sxa-search

I have to do the search with my data folder items. I have defined the search scope with location, still, it's not coming in the result. I have inherited my template with

/Sitecore/Templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Search/Computed Fields/_Searchable

still it's not coming.
[image]

I have already referred these two, no luck

[How can I modify SXA search component to search also in the Accordions content?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/how-can-i-modify-sxa-search-component-to-search-also-in-the-accordions-content)

[How to make SXA search on particular Data folder?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27501/how-to-make-sxa-search-on-particular-data-folder)

Comment: For what reason do you "have to" search in the data folder items? Why not create a folder under the content tree of items which are not pages but still searchable content?

Comment: And what do you mean with "search"? What are you going to do with the results? Just asking as you will not be able to link to them.. and they have no layout as well (which is in many sxa queries a requirement as this checks if it is an actual page)

Comment: @MichaelWest We were asked to create the data source item under the Data folder. So I followed the requirement. Can we do the search for data source item?

Comment: @Gatogordo We are using the Rendering variant for showing results. so no need for pages and layout.so we are configure the values in datasource and reading that since it is not pages

Comment: You should add some information to the question: what rendering are you using? But most important: what are you trying to achieve? And I mean this in a functional way - not a technical. You might be on the wrong track but without this information it's hard to help.

Comment: What kind of data are you storing that requires it to be under Data?

Comment: @MichaelWest I'm trying to so the partner details in my search result section. There are more than 100 partners, I don't want to show the partner on the page, it is just the data. I like to keep the partners in the data and build a new search page, my customers can filter all the partner's regions vise and they can see all the partners there. I'm using the rendering variant for showing details in the result section.

Comment: @Gatogordo I have added the functional requirement in above comment, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resolved the above issue. I have followed two steps

**Step 1:**

```
Inherit searchable with your template
```

[image]

**Step 2:**

```
Add Search scope with your data source location with +sign
```

[image]

**Step 3:**

Go to Settings, Add your datasource folder in Associated content

[image]